# Facebook Login Flow Returning Status "unknown"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, I recently created an FB that is available to all users and to the best of my knowledge, is not in sandbox mode. I used the sample code that provided in the documentation on the FB Developers Website and placed it on localhost. The settings "App Domains" and "Site URL" are all correct. So, even when I log into FB, upon logging in, in Chrome's JS console, it reads `statusChangeCallback splash.php:60
Object {status: "unknown", authResponse: null}`

I have used the following code

```
<script>
    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);

        if(response.status === 'connected') {
            testAPI();
        } else if(response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into Facebook.';
        }
    }

    // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
    // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
    // code below.
    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: "I'm not dumb",
            //cookie: true,  
            status: true,
            xfbml: true,  
            oauth: true,
            version: 'v2.1' 
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            alert(response);
            if(response.status === 'connected') {
            if(response.authResponse != 'undefined') {
                    window.location = '<?php echo $base_url; ?>register';
                        }
            } else if(response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                        // it means we have a user but he hasn't granted any permissions to our app
                        // we're going to redirect him to the permission page
            } else {
                        //the user is not logged in, as you already have a login button you don't have to do nothing  
            }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
            window.location = '<?php echo $base_url; ?>register';
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
    // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response + '!';
    });
    }
</script>

<fb:login-button scope="" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening and I've never run into this problem before.

Comment: Why are you calling `FB.getLoginStatus()` two times?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked through you code,

you have edited the js code.

Restore your current js code with the code which you can find in the below link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1